# Producer's accuracy export in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I'm calculating a **Producer's accuracy** in Google Earth Engine and I can't export it as a table or CSV to do the rest of my work in Python.

Is there any way to export it?

I already tried  `export.table.toDrive` but it doesn't work!
here is my code:

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: (ee.Element(confusionMatrix98_99.producersAccuracy())),
  description: 'Producers_accuracy400_99',
  folder: 'earthengine',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding question on GIS SE should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Answer (score 2):

The `collection` property must be a feature collection. Just add your  producer accuracy as a property in a feature in a feature collection, then export.
va

```
r producersAccuracy = confusionMatrix98_99.producersAccuracy()
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(null, {producersAccuracy: producersAccuracy})),
  description: 'Producers_accuracy400_99',
  folder: 'earthengine',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: ['producersAccuracy']
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/eea5ea8653a5e70e6325abd3a7e23e80

Comment: thank you so much!
It did work.